# How does 生まれ translate in this context?

Tags: grammar, words, song-lyrics

今日、[この歌](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1awua0YrSRs)を聞きました。

最初の歌詞はこれです：

> アイデンティティがない　生まれない　らららら

でも意味が分かりません。英訳するができない。

「(If you) have no identity, (you) haven't been born」と思いますが、確かめたいです。

日本語で説明していい。

Comment: The subject of アイデンティティがない is 僕(は). The subject of 生まれない is (my) アイデンティティ.

Comment: 答えてくれてありがとう！

それじゃ、英訳は："(I have) no identity, (it) hasn't been born"と言うのは正しいですか？

Comment: 生まれない は 過去 ではなく、未来の推測(文法的には現在形だけれども)。

Comment: @jovanni The subject of <whatever>-ga nai cannot be boku, because people require "inai".  The grammatical subject there is "アイデンティティ"; it is identity which is "doing" the "action" of not existing. Boku is rather the (understood) topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下手ではありますが... Not a strict translation.

> ```
> アイデンティティがない 生まれない? ららら
> アイデンティティがない 生まれない ららら
>
> I have no identity.
> Can I have such an identity? la-la-la.
>
> 好きな服はなんですか?好きな本は?好きな食べ物は何?
> そう そんな物差しを持ち合わせてる僕は凡人だ
>
> What kind of clothes do you like? 
> What is your favorite book and food?
>
> What a featureless man I am, 
> who think that everyone can be distinguishable from others by such questions.
>
> 映し鏡 ショーウィンドー 隣の人と自分を見比べる 
> そう それが真っ当と思い込んで生きていた 
> どうして 今になって 今になって そう僕は考えたんだろう?
>
> Comparing me and my neibourghs through the reflecting image of show windows,
> I lived till now that to think such way was very natural.
>
> I become to think that the favorite book, foods nor clothes are not
> the essaential part of my identity.
> I had never such a thought till now, why?
>
> どうして まだ見えない 自分らしさってやつに 朝は来るのか?
>
> How can it be happen that the identity which I have never seen 
> be born and it sees the sun shine of morning.
> ```